# Selected CC address move to Selected folder in office 365 outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I want move selected **cc** address to selected folder in outlook office 365 (Using rule or VBA script)

**Ex- Received one email from "abc@zyz.com" and in this mail "xyz@abc.com" is in CC.**
So i want move **xyz@abc.com** to **"Purchase-Dept"** folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Outlook rules and VBA macros can be run in the Outlook desktop only.

You can set up a rule in Outlook or create a VBA macro. Your VBA macro can also be called from a rule if it triggers and should look in the following way:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  ' here your actions
End Sub
```

Also you can implement the required functionality in VBA only. For that you need to declare a method where you could check the `To` and `Cc` properties of Outlook items. But better yet is to use the `Recipients` property for checking such fields. Be also aware that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items, so I'd recommend checking the item's [MessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.messageclass) property which returns or sets a string representing the message class for the Outlook item, see [Item Types and Message Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes) for more information about their correspondence.